# How to undo @tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable

Tags: keras, serialization, tensorflow2.0

You use this to register a func into keras serialization framework. I did this in a notebook cell:

```
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
def foo():
  return tf.constant(1)
```

But if I need to make changes to the method, you will get a `ValueError: [...] has already been registered to [...]`.

Is there a way to unregister whatever that was, and then re-register with the updated func?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

In Tensorflow Version 2.9.2 this can be done via:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects().clear()
```

The `tf.keras.utils.method get_custom_objects()` returns the dict `_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS` that contains all the methods added by `@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()`.

So including

```
tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects().clear()
```

after importing tensorflow fixes this ValueError, at least in IPython Console from Spyder that I used for testing.